# How can we display a text in exactly 4 lines and only then implement horizontal scroll in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can we display a **text** in precisely **4 lines** and introduce **horizontal scrolling **in the 4th line only if the text **exceeds the space allotted**(i.e.four lines)?

I tried the following but it shows everything in single line with horizontal scrolling.
If I comment out  `.horizontalScroll(scrollState)`, then it shows only 4 lines and no scrolling.

```
Text(
            text = "In this blog post, " +
                    "we will explore how to implement a countdown timer" +
                    " using Jetpack Compose, the modern toolkit for building " +
                    "native Android UI. We will start with a basic timer and" +
                    " gradually add more advanced features." +
                    "we will explore how to implement a countdown timer" +
                    "using Jetpack Compose, the modern toolkit for building " +
                    "native Android UI. We will start with a basic timer and" +
                    "gradually add more advanced features.",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
            maxLines = 4,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            modifier = Modifier
                .horizontalScroll(scrollState)
        )
```

Comment: You only have 1 line of text here-  there's no newlines to break it up.  So if you make it scrollable, it's going to be one long scrollable line.